# Output several values from array to MessageBox line by line

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, masm32

I have a program that solves a math problem 5 times with different values using a loop. It stores the result in `result` array, so in the end I need to show these values each starting from a new line:

```
result[0]
result[4]
result[8]
result[12]
result[16]
```

But I don't seem to understand how to implement this in my code, all methods I tried did not work. Right now it just shows 1 result. I understand, that a way to start a new line is `,10`, but I just don't know where to put it right.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
titletext db 'Лаб 5', 0
AnswerTxt db 'The answer is '
AnswerNum db 11 dup(0)
num_a dd 5,-5,-25,25,-5
num_b dd 5,32,3,-5,6
num_c dd 10,2,8,12,4
bracket dd ?
result dd ?,?,?,?,?

.code
start:
    mov esi, 5
    mov edi, 0
    .Repeat
        mov eax, -25
        mov ebx, num_a[edi]
        cdq
        idiv ebx
        add eax, num_c[edi]
        mov bracket, eax
        mov eax, num_b[edi]
        mov ebx, num_a[edi]
        cdq
        imul ebx
        sub bracket, eax
        mov eax, num_c[edi]
        mov ebx, num_b[edi]
        cdq
        imul ebx
        mov ebx, 2
        cdq
        idiv ebx
        add eax, 1
        mov ebx, bracket
        cdq
        imul ebx
        mov result[edi], eax

        mov ebx, 2
        cdq
        idiv ebx

        .IF edx == 0
            mov eax, result[edi]
            mov ebx, 2
            cdq
            idiv ebx
        .ELSE
            mov eax, result[edi]
            mov ebx, 5
            cdq
            imul ebx
        .ENDIF

        mov result[edi], eax
        add edi, 4
        dec esi
        .Until Zero?

        push offset AnswerNum
        push result[12]
        call dwtoa
        push 0
        push offset titletext
        push offset AnswerTxt
        push 0
        call MessageBox
        call ExitProcess
end start
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `wsprintf` or some other similar function, where you can place the newline characters directly in the format string?

Comment: @Michael could you provide a bit of example or some info on how could I adapt this in my code, if you have time and opportunity? I just started getting into asm and the MessageBox output and the `AnswerNum` is from a more simple adding calculator example. I don't even understand why we need to reserve this space to put a ASCIIed integer there later on.

Comment: MASM32 comes with plenty of examples, and several of them use `wsprintf`. For example, `examples\exampl02\dir` and `examples\exampl03\lcd`.

Comment: @Michael thank you! Will look in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall
option casemap:none

include \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.data
titletext db  'Лаб 5',0
frmt db  '1 = %d',10
     db  '2 = %d',10
     db  '3 = %d',10
     db  '4 = %d',10
     db  '5 = %d',0
buff db  256 dup (0)
result dd ?,?,?,?,?
```

and after filling the `result[0],result[4],result[8],result[12],result[16]` array:

```
        invoke  wsprintf,addr buff,addr frmt,result[0],result[4],result[8],result[12],result[16]
        invoke  MessageBox,0,addr buff,addr titletext,MB_OK
        invoke  ExitProcess,0
end start
```

also you can use **crt_sprintf** function, it is even a little bit more flexible enabling to use floats.